# are disk drill 3 dmg whole system backup images the same as macos disk utility dmg backup images? / would I need to create boot usb to use them?

Tags: backup, time-machine, usb, ssd, dmg

I have a small and slow ssd on an old macbook, I want to upgrade the ssd one day, but keep my old macbook because I don't have much money and I like it.

I have auto time machine backups to a usb and clone sometimes on another usb, but I want to upload whole system dmg to a cloud service, as a third backup, so I have an option of using it to restore to my bigger newer ssd.

I have a third party proram called disk drill 3 that easily makes system dmg, or I could use native disk utility, will they be the exact same? and also when I put my new bigger ssd in and it's empty, will it be required to make a recovery boot disk usb beforehand to even get to recovery menu, and then load the dmg (which will downloaded from cloud to another usb at that point from another pc), from there?

system details:

macbook air 11" mid 2012

catalina 10.15.6

disk drill 3 pro is the third party program, 3.8.965 pro

I can click my main system drive there and select backup into DMG-image as opposed to creating dmg from disk utility from catalina.

thanks for any responses.

Comment: I’m not going to cast a close vote, but can you look at [help] and add some details? All is a broad ask - all versions of macOS are very different, all backup tools means those that are known not to work. I 5ink perhaps you have a very narrow question about one specific version of macOS and finding one tool you understand how to use perhaps?

Comment: I will edit to include more information.